# Php else statement not working well

Tags: php, mysql

Hey guys  i am new to php development and  came across with a project in php ..

## My html code

```
<html>
<body>
<form name="input" action="database.php" method="post">
Username: <input type="text" name="user">
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

## php code

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$name = $_POST['user'];

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )

{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$sql = 'SELECT username, phoneno FROM test';

mysql_select_db('test');

$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

if(! $retval )

{



 die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());

}


while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($retval,MYSQL_ASSOC))

{

if($name != $row['username']) {

        echo "this username is not in our db";

} else {
echo "you are logged in";

}
}

mysql_close($conn);

?>
```

Here the user is allowded to login by giving his username and if the username is not in the database he must get a message `this is not in out db`.But when i typed a username which doesnt exist in our db it gives me message 3 times like `this username is not in our db you are logged in this username is not in our db`..Here the else part code and actual code are working together ..why is it like this ..Hope you guys can help me ,

Comment: Go & learn some basics of PHP. http://php.net/

Comment: Your query is retrieving all the rows from your database and your `while` loop is then checking your input against every row and echoing a message for each of them. Add a `WHERE` clause to your query.

Comment: `if...else` is working the exact way it has to.

Comment: try changing the symbol in the if statement. also you should do "or die" instead of an if statement.

Comment: symbol in if statement ?

Comment: can show a dump of your data?

Comment: @Placeholders_in_use i have tried it but it didnt worked ..

Comment: @MahasishShome if you are such an expert tell the ans here ..:P

Comment: @user3682085 I figured out your mistake. I am writing the answer just check it out if it solves your problem.

Comment: ok write it then ..thanks for your help ..

Comment: @user3682085 Don't be so angry gentleman. I am always telling people **DON'T use mysql_** use mysqli_* or PDO as it is deprecated as of PHP 5.5 Mysql_* deprecation notice http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

Comment: i know ...many people are recomending mysqli .,i just did it for testing bro ..if you know the answer please share..

Comment: are you done with your answer ..

Comment: @user3682085 Yes, you may check my answer & let me know if you are getting your problem solved or you still have any problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Steps to solve the problem:

1) We are checking in the database if there is any entry with `username = $_POST['user']`

2) If we don't find an entry then `echo "this username is not in our db"` or else `echo "you are logged in"`

**My HTML code**

```
<html>
<body>
<form name="input" action="database.php" method="post">
Username: <input type="text" name="user">
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP code**

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$dbname = 'test';
$name = $_POST['user'];

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

if(!$conn){ die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_connect_error()); }

$retval = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT username, phoneno FROM test WHERE username='".$name."'");

if(mysqli_num_rows($retval)<1){

    echo "this username is not in our db";

} else {

    echo "you are logged in";

}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Your Mistake :

1) You were looping the entire table & hence it was generating 3 output at the same time

Comment: May I know why my answer got a Downvote though it is accepted by the OP?

Answer (score 0):

You're looping through all rows in your table and hence on each iteration, either one of the `if-else` statement is getting executed.

To overcome this, you can do something like this:

```
$users = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($retval,MYSQL_ASSOC))    
{
   $users[] = $row['username']; // store all usernames in an array
}

// now check for your condition
// in_array checks for existence of a string inside an array ($users)
if(in_array($name, $users)) {
   echo "You are logged in";
} else {
   echo "This username is not in our db";
}
```